# Transparent Select/Option text in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've created the JS fiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/C8NUf/1/

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>
        Test
    </option>
    <option>
        Another Test
    </option>
</select>
```

Style:

```
select {
    color: transparent;
}
```

In chrome, the selected text "test" is properly blanked out by setting the color to transparent, in IE the test is still black.

How can I fix this issue in IE? Ideally I want to make this change via JQuery, but that doesn't seem very relevant to the overall problem.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Which version of IE are you trying to get this to work with?

Comment: IE 9 & 10 are my targets

Answer (score 0):

Do you try put?

```
display:none
```

This hide object. I know that you want use color transparent but IE is trash.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is a comprehensive answer for all browsers](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)

Essentially, you have to define your transparency differently to support non-compliant browsers.

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Then just add `transparent` as a class to your `select`s.

Comment: This doesn't take care of the issue I'm looking for at all, I don't want the element to be transparent I want the text within the selected item to be transparent. Equivalent to what it'd look like if you had a <option></option> as the first element in your list.